# Add optgroup with options to select with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, optgroup

my question is simple but yet I didn't find a clear example of doing that.
I'm trying to add optgroup for a select and fill it with options using jquery for some reason it's not working.
this is my code:

```
$('#ptype').change(function() {
        $.post(
                   "/sell/site/index/categories", 
                   {
                      'parent_id': $('#ptype').val()
                   }, 
                   function(response){
                       var categories = $.parseJSON(response);

                       $('#sub_category').empty();
                        $.each(categories, function (index) {

                            var optgroup = $('<optgroup/>');

                            $.each(this.children, function (index) {
                                optgroup.add($("<option></option>")
                                            .attr("value",index)
                                            .text(this)); 
                            });

                            $("#sub_category").append(optgroup);

                        });

                        $("#sub_category").multiselect('refresh'); //refresh the select here
                    }
                );
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `$.parseJSON()` - set a `dataType` of `'json'` and jQuery will parse it automatically and pass the result to your callback. If you don't set the data type explictly jQuery makes an intelligent guess based on the response, so it may still try to parse it for you in which case your attempt to parse it again with `$.parseJSON()` won't work.

Answer (score 18):

Ok so I figured out the solution myself in the end, however, thanks for the useful tips from you guys.
here's the working code:

```
$('#ptype').change(
            function() {
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: "/sell/site/index/categories",
                  data: { 'parent_id': $('#ptype').val() },
                  success: function(data){ updateCategories(data); },
                  dataType: 'json'
            })
        }
    );

function updateCategories(categories){
         $('#sub_category').empty();
         $.each(categories, function (index) {
            var optgroup = $('<optgroup>');
            optgroup.attr('label',categories[index].name);

             $.each(categories[index].children, function (i) {
                var option = $("<option></option>");
                option.val(i);
                option.text(categories[index].children[i]);

                optgroup.append(option);
             });
             $("#sub_category").append(optgroup);

         });

         $("#sub_category").multiselect('refresh'); //refresh the select here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
  $.each($(this).children(), function (index) {
```

instead of

```
  $.each(this.children, function (index) {
```

`this` refers to the DOM element itself; `$(this)` wraps the element up in a jQuery object.

and you don't have to use parseJson..(if u have specified the response as json (dataType)).

```
var categories = $.parseJSON(response);
```

go through this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/. u can directly use response in $.each function .. (make sure u have responce in the format u wanted)..

Comment: That's for the useful tips, I changed my code, however, it didn't fix my problem.